# resolve the server hostname of a dnsmasq server with multiple subnets

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I have a self-made Linux router running dnsmasq. It has two different NICs through which clients are connected; one of them has the subnet `192.168.1.` and one the subnet `192.168.2.`. My `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` looks like this:

```
except-interface=enp1s0
dhcp-range=interface:wlp2s0,192.168.1.10,192.168.1.25,255.255.255.0,48h
dhcp-range=interface:enp0s29f7u4,192.168.2.10,192.168.2.25,255.255.255.0,48h
```

Resolving the clients works between subnets, but from neither subnet can I resolve the hostname of the server itself. If I add a static rule using `address=/name/IP` I have to choose on of the subnets and pinging (among other things) does not work from the other subnet. So for example if I set

```
address=/name/192.168.1.1
```

then I can resolve the hostname from the `192.168.2.` subnet, but pings are unanswered. How do I solve that situation? I would like not having to bridge the interfaces or something like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, in your case, the server have an address for each subnet: 192.168.1.1 and the other could be 192.168.2.1

I guess you want the clients to receive the server address of its corresponding subnet.

I had the same problem, found answer in http://t7994.network-dns-dnsmasq-general.dnstalk.us/multi-homed-server-with-same-hostname-on-2-subnets-t7994.html

Check "-y, --localise-queries" in the dnsmasq man page.

You can put "localise-queries" in dnsmasq.conf too, and put the two server address entries the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Btw: This also works when putting the line `localise-queries` into `dnsmasq.conf`.